# Editable combobox with list autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, accessibility

So, I have a modal and the escape key closes it. Inside the modal, I have an *editable combobox with list autocomplete* and in theory, pressing the escape key should close/clear the listbox.

My doubt is about the modal. I'm just preventing the excape key press to reach the modal listener when the focus is in the editable combobox but not sure if that's the best practice or maybe if the combobox is closed/empty the event should be bubbled to the modal.

What's the best practice or what could be better for the person using the form?

Comment: Yes, when the user is editing the model shouldn't be closed. if closed user entered data will be cleared. My suggestion is better to prevent close events when focusing on editable field.

Answer (score 1):

If you compare with what native OS usually do,

- Escape should close the combobox when it is open, and the focus returns to the edition field
- Escape should close the whole dialog box when the combobox is not open

You can for example experiment it using the Run dialog box of Windows.
It's generally a good idea to behave as much as possible like OS are doing for years.

However, as far as I know, pressing escape generally don't clear the input. It isn't standard, or at least not under Windows, though it is sometimes done and can indeed be quite useful.